# Dependency Injection Trying to Pass Non-Service for Layered Abstract Component in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, abstract-class

I have an Angular component for a modal such that the content of the modal can be passed in like so:

SomeComponent.html:

```
<my-modal-component>
     <div> all my content for the modal of SomeComponent goes here!</div>
</my-modal-component>
```

And `my-modal-component` handles setting up things such as the modal styling, close button, etc.

To extend some options to all of my modals and the components making use of these modals, I have created an abstract class called `my-abstract-component`, which **is not actually a component**, but a class that has a similar setup and functions that each component should have (error handling, setup/tear-down, etc.)

My problem is that I cannot get the required **non-service information** from `SomeComponent` as a modal into `MyAbstractComponent`.

SomeComponent.ts, the component with all the content that will go into the modal.

```
@Component({ ... })
export class SomeComponent extends MyModalComponent{
    public constructor(    
        @Inject(LoggerService)  logger: LoggerService, // these services are injected as normal
        @Inject(NgbActiveModal) activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
    ) {
        super(activeModal, logger, Components.MyModalComponent);
    }
    ...
}
```

MyModalComponent.ts, the modal component that takes in content but also has its own content. It contains some shared modal functionality like closing the modal. It extends MyAbstractComponent since it is also a component.

```
@Component({...}) // this is a real component with a view and module, so it's tagged as such
export class MyModalComponent extends MyAbstractComponent{
    public constructor(
        protected activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
        protected logger: LoggerService,
        component: IComponent, // THIS IS MY PROBLEM
    ) {
        super(logger, component);
    }
    ...
}
```

MyModalModule.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ MyModalComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        NgbModule
    ],
    providers: [
        LoggerService
        // is it possible to somehow put the IComponent here?
    ],
    exports: [ MyModalComponent, ],
    entryComponents: [ MyModalComponent, ]
})
export class MyModalModule{ }
```

MyAbstractComponent.ts, the abstract component for *all* components, includes common functions like logging errors, setup, tear-down, etc.

```
/* Acts like a component, but is not flagged as a real component because it doesn't have a view or module*/
export abstract class MyAbstractComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    public constructor(
        protected logger: LoggerService,
        protected component: IComponent, // content passed in the constructor because it's not real dependency injection of services
    ) {
        this.logger= logger;
        this.component = component;
    }
    ...
}
```

The information I'm trying to pass is information used for logging, here is an example of `Components.MyModalComponent`:

```
export namespace Components {
    export const MyModalComponent: IComponent = {
        userFriendlyName: "My Modal Component",
        ...
    };
}
```

As you can see, I need to get some component information from the top level component class (`SomeComponent`) down multiple levels into MyAbstractComponent`. If I only had to go through one level, I can pass the component info via the super constructor. However, since this component info needs to go through a second layer of a component where only services can be part of the injection in the component, I receive this error regarding the DI:

`ERROR in Can't resolve all parameters for MyModalComponent in MyModalComponent.ts: ([object Object], [object Object], ?).`

Where the `?` is the component info that is not a service.

I could pass in the required info in different ways (via `@Input` or with a getter/setter), but in a perfect world everything would be ready in the constructor. I feel confident someone else has faced and solved this issue before. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is Components.MyModalComponent ? Is an instance of MyModalComponent ? 
Please, put the code of Components class.

Comment: @Rodrigo it's just information such as names of the components for logging. I've included an instance of it for reference. Please see my edits.